# How do I call a 32-bit DLL using .NET/Link and a 64-bit version of Mathematica?

Tags: interoperability, .netlink

The .NET/Link tutorial shows how to call functions defined in DLLs.  The example uses the [`GetTickCount` Win32 API function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724408%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

```
<< NetLink`
InstallNET[]
getTickCount = DefineDLLFunction["GetTickCount", "kernel32.dll", "int", {}]

getTickCount[]

(* ==> 91226108 *)
```

Unfortunately this does not work by default when usign a 64-bit version of Mathematica to call a function defined in a 32-bit DLL.  Let's use the 32-bit version of `kernel32.dll` to test:

```
getTickCount = 
 DefineDLLFunction["GetTickCount", "c:\\windows\\SysWOW64\\kernel32.dll", "int", {}]

getTickCount[]

NET::netexcptn: A .NET exception occurred: System.BadImageFormatException: 
   An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. 
   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)
   at Wolfram.NETLink.DynamicDLLNamespace.DLLWrapper15.GetTickCount().
```

How can I call a 32-bit DLL from a 64-bit Mathematica?

Comment: I thought this will be valuable for the community.  It's based on a MathGroup question I solved.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The solution is forcing .NET/Link to load its 32-bit executable instead of the 64-bit one.  Since Mathematica communicated with the .NET/Link process through MathLink, it does not matter if the Mathematica kernel is 64 bit and the .NET/Link executable is a 32 bit version.  They are separate processes.  However, the .NET/Link executable must match the DLL that is being loaded.

There is an undocumented option to force loading the 32-bit version of .NET/Link:

```
UninstallNET[]
InstallNET["Force32Bit" -> True]
```

Now 32-bit DLLs can be loaded through .NET/Link, but 64-bit ones cannot.

Answer (score 12):

Or simply use

```
ReinstallNET["Force32Bit" -> True]
```

which is a [convenience function](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/NETLink/ref/ReinstallNET.html) that calls

```
UninstallNET[]
InstallNET["Force32Bit" -> True]
```

Comment: I indeed learned `ReinstallNET["Force32Bit"->True]` in [Integrating C and Mathematica](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/7996/) by Joel F. Klein and Todd Gayley